# Bash: how to get the first number that occurs in a variable's content

Tags: bash

how to get the first number of variables

I have a variable:

```
STR="My horse weighs 3000 kg but the car weighs more"
STR="Maruska found 000011 mushrooms but only 001 was not with meat"
STR="Yesterday I almost won the lottery 0000020 CZK but in the end it was only 05 CZK"
```

I need to get the numbers:

```
3000
11
20
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is one way to do it:

```
echo $STR | grep -o -E '[0-9]+' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^0\+//'
```

Test:

```
$ STR="My horse weighs 3000 kg but the car weighs more"
$ echo $STR | grep -o -E '[0-9]+' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^0\+//'
3000

$ STR="Maruska found 000011 mushrooms but only 001 was not with meat"
$ echo $STR | grep -o -E '[0-9]+' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^0\+//'
11

$ STR="Yesterday I almost won the lottery 0000020 CZK but in the end it was only 05 CZK"
$ echo $STR | grep -o -E '[0-9]+' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^0\+//'
20
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `sed` at the end?  It seems like before it goes into sed we already have the result we want.

Comment: No, you have for #2 `000011` for which you have to remove the leadings zeros. But you could simplify by matching `[1-9][0-9]*` which would remove the leading zeroes from the start :     
`echo $STR | grep -o -E '[1-9][0-9]*'`

Answer (score 7):

With gawk, set the record separator `RS` to a sequence of digits. The text that matched the `RS` pattern can be retrieved via`RT`. Add `0` to `RT` to force it to a number (thus dropping the leading zeroes). Exit as soon as the first instance is printed

```
awk -v RS=[0-9]+ '{print RT+0;exit}' <<< "$STR"
```

Or here is a bash solution

```
shopt -s extglob
read -r Z _ <<< "${STR//[^[:digit:] ]/}"
echo ${Z##+(0)}
```

Comment: Nice. Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: I don't get it. What am I doing wrong (with the awk version)? https://gist.github.com/jamiejackson/d92750cc42442a527c6b94499a13bc79

Comment: @JamieJackson, make sure you're running GNU awk aka gawk

Answer (score 3):

If your implementation of `grep` doesn't have `-o` or if you're not using Bash, you can do the following:

```
printf "%.0f\n" $(printf "%s" "$string"|sed  's/^[^0-9]*//;s/[^0-9].*$//')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

string="My horse weighs 3000 kg but the car weighs more"

if [[ $string =~ ^([a-zA-Z\ ]*)([0-9]*)(.*)$ ]]
then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Comment: The subscript should be 2 instead of 1. But you really don't need that complex of a regex. It would fail anyway if there were other characters in the string.

Answer (score 2):

I've put your strings in an array so it can easily be iterated for this demonstration.

This uses Bash's builtin regular expression matching.

Only a very simple pattern is required. It's recommended to use a variable to hold the pattern instead of incorporating it directly in the match test. It's essential for more complex patterns.

```
str[0]="My horse weighs 3000 kg but the car weighs more"
str[1]="Maruska found 000011 mushrooms but only 001 was not with meat"
str[2]="Yesterday I almost won the lottery 0000020 CZK but in the end it was only 05 CZK"

patt='([[:digit:]]+)'

for s in "${str[@]}"; do [[ $s =~ $patt ]] && echo "[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}] - $s"; done
```

I included the square brackets only to visually set off the numbers.

Output:

```
[3000] - My horse weighs 3000 kg but the car weighs more
[000011] - Maruska found 000011 mushrooms but only 001 was not with meat
[0000020] - Yesterday I almost won the lottery 0000020 CZK but in the end it was only 05 CZK
```

To get the numbers without the leading zeroes, the easiest way is to force a base-10 conversion.

```
echo "$(( 10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ))"
```

Substituting that, the output looks like what you requested:

```
3000
11
20
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up regular expressions and `man grep`.

```
echo $STR | grep -o [0-9]*
```

and to remove the leading zeros, treat it as a number:

```
LIT=$(echo $STR | grep -o [0-9]*)
VAL=$(expr $LIT + 0)
echo $VAL
```

Comment: Your solution fails with variables contains two number or the number padding zero.