# Find the first number, then return the rest of the string

Tags: bash, text-processing

Using Bash, how can I find the first number in a string and then take the rest of the string?

For example, I have the following string -

> SomeText.MoreText.Whatever.1.2.3.4-branch.ext

And I wish to end up with this -

> 1.2.3.4-branch.ext

I've found several answers that suggest how to find numbers (such as [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92208/bash-how-to-get-the-first-number-that-occurs-in-a-variables-content)), but nothing that finds and returns a portion of a string.

Comment: I have solved this using `grep` and a basic regular expression. What have you tried this far?

Comment: @maulinglawns - "I have solved this using grep and a basic regular expression" - Care to share?  After all, isn't that the idea of a question/answer site such as this...

Comment: @maulinglawns - Actually, don't worry, someone esle was kind enough to share an answer.

Comment: `[[ $string =~ [0-9].* ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH`

Comment: @SatoKatsura - Thanks for the contribution, that also does the job just fine.

Comment: @DavidGard Absolutely! I am all for sharing. That's why I am active here, but the thing with sharing is that it goes both ways. Best regards.

Comment: @maulinglawns - Well that makes no sense - you are basically saying you won't answer my question unless I do something for you first. Thanks any way.

Comment: @DavidGard No, that's not my point at all. I was merely curious to see **your** approach. Does that make more sense? Best regards.

Comment: @maulinglawns - So you are assuming I have used Linux before today?  I had no approach, hench the question.  If you aim is to help people learn, rather than doing it for them, may I suggest you that you make a recommendation.  For example, had you said "Check out the grep command, it'll do what you need", that would have been helpful.

Comment: @DavidGard You are right, that would have been a better choice of words. And yes, my aim is indeed to try and help when I can. You make some valid points, appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `grep`, extracting only the matched portion (`-o`):

```
grep -o '[0-9].*'
```

- `[0-9]` will match the first digit, and `.*` will match the rest

**Example:**

```
$ grep -o '[0-9].*' <<<'SomeText.MoreText.Whatever.1.2.3.4-branch.ext'
1.2.3.4-branch.ext
```

Comment: This does the same in most POSIX shells without the need (and the time expense) of calling an external utility: `echo "${var#"${var%%[0-9]*}"}"`.

Comment: @sorontar, please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and available in most POSIX shells is:

```
$ var='SomeText.MoreText.Whatever.1.2.3.4-branch.ext'

$ echo "${var#"${var%%[0-9]*}"}"
1.2.3.4-branch.ext
```

In this way there is no need to call any external utility (expr, sed, awk, etc) and the time expense to call such utility is also avoided (for short strings such as in this case, for long strings (10's of k's) the shell is very slow).